# How do I fix this error: Task 'wrapper' not found in project ':app'

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

All my projects report this error? Is there a setting or option I need to change to resolve this error?

```
app: failed At 9/30/2021 2:47 PM with 1 error
   Task 'wrapper' not found in project ':app'.

Task 'wrapper' not found in project ':app'

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack
```

[image: Photo of the errors]

Comment: am not sure , but try using this command using cmd . gradle wrapper . this will generate your gradlew and gradlew.bat

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem that was causing this error. I just selected the app folder inside project folder. when I selected project root folder the build works. Again Thank You for The Help. :) –

Comment: Make sure you have a gradle folder at the project root with a gradle-wrapper.jar and gradle-wrapper.properties.

Comment: Click on Gradle tool window and you'll found the cause.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

This is because your build.gradle file doesn't have a wrapper task. Add this code to build.gradle:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper){
   gradleVersion = '7.2'
}
```

You can replace 7.2 with the gradle version you want, then run `gradle wrapper` task.

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem that was causing this error. I just selected the app folder inside project folder. when I selected project root folder the build works. Again Thank You for The Help. :)

Comment: Which `build.gradle`, there are 2. `android/build.gradle` and `android/app/build.gradle`.

Comment: @MikeS. The root build.gradle, aka project-name\build.gradle

Comment: My issue relates to react native. There's a .env file that needs to be passed to the launcher. From CLI, it's easy. I run `ENVFILE=.env.stg npx react-native run-android`. From AS, I need to pass that param, but not sure how. That would probably fix my problem.

Comment: If I add the code snippet you posted here, I am told that it already exists: 
`Cannot add task 'wrapper' as a task with that name already exists.`
If I remove it, I get the same error as the original poster. To me it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AnnaMadsen facing same problem. Have you found any solution ?

Comment: @MichealChoudhary No, I don't think I ever figured it out

Comment: where do you add that?

Answer (score 24):

maybe your project's structure is :

---

```
yourProjectDir:  
 --> app:  
    --> build.gradle  
 --> otherModule1:  
 --> otherModule2:  
 --> build.gradle
```

---

The correct way to open the project is :
Click *build.gradle* in the root directory 'yourProjectDir', not *build.gradle* in the 'app' dir.

Comment: Good point, solved my problem !

Answer (score 18):

[image]

Unlink unnecessary Gradle project and it will be fixed.

Comment: Thanks, I spent a lot of time trying to get what is wrong. Looks like Idea's generated.

Comment: That's work perfectly, you need also to reload the gradle projects

Answer (score 2):

For Kotlin:
Here's the correct way to define the wrapper task in your build.gradle.kts file:

```
tasks.register<Wrapper>("wrapper") {
   gradleVersion = "5.6.4"
}
```

In this Kotlin DSL code, use the register function to create a new task of type Wrapper and configure its properties within the lambda block.

Note: Make sure to replace '5.6.4' with the desired version of Gradle that you want to use for your project.

Answer (score 1):

If the "unlink" option does not exist in your Gradle settings, you can manually unlink the "app" project by removing its entry from the root/.idea/gradle.xml configuration file.

[image: Delete the .idea entry for the undesired Gradle project]

Answer (score 0):

**Task 'wrapper' not found in project ':app'.

- Try:
  Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.  Run with --scan to get full insights.

**